# twitter clone - trying to show the users username next to their tweet on tweets index - devise

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I'm trying to create a twitter clone. I'm at the point where a user can post a tweet and it shows the content and the time it was posted. However i want it so the username is also next to the tweet of whoever tweeted it.
i'm unsure how to do this as the error is currently 'Couldn't find User without an ID' in my tweet controller create method. I'm also not sure of the syntax to display the username in index.html.erb.
thanks.

```html
class TweetsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @tweets = Tweet.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @tweet = Tweet.new
    # @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    # @tweet = Tweet.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
    @tweet.user = @user
    if @tweet.save
    redirect_to tweets_path
  end
  end

  def edit
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
    @tweet.update(tweet_params)
    redirect_to tweets_path
  end

  private
  def tweet_params
    params.require(:tweet).permit(:user_id,:content)
  end
end
```

```html
<h1>TWEETS</h1>

<%# @users.each do |user| %>
<%#= user.username %>
<%# end %>

<%= simple_form_for @tweet, id: "form-submit" do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :content, label: "Tweet" %>
   <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
   <% end %>

   <br>

<% @tweets.each do |tweet|  %>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <%= tweet.created_at.strftime("%B %d %Y, %l:%M%P") %> <br>
      <%= tweet.content %>
      <%#= tweet.user.username %>
    <%#= tweet.user.username %>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the relation between your users and tweets table

in your tweet model add

```
 class Tweet < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user 
    end
```

and in your user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :tweets 
end
```

`rails g migration AddUserIdToMessages` and in this migration

```
def change 
   add_column :tweets, :user_id, :integer 
end
```

After that you can user  `<%= tweet.user.username %>`in your view to show the username

---

My test :
Controller

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @tweets = Tweet.all.order("created_at DESC") 
  end
end
```

Model

```
class Tweet < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

View (index.html.erb)

```
<% @tweets.each do |tweet|  %>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <%= tweet.created_at.strftime("%B %d %Y, %l:%M%P") %> <br>
      <p> Content : <%= tweet.content %></p>
      Username : <%= tweet.user.username %>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Route

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get 'tweet/index', to: 'tweets#index'
    end
```

seed.rb (for testing)

```
User.create({username: "myName"})
Tweet.create({content: "hello",user_id: 1})
```

and `run rake db:seed`

and dont forget to add

```
def change 
   add_column :tweets, :user_id, :integer 
end
```

In the generated migration.

[image]

Comment: thanks, however it seems the has_many :tweets in tweet model is stopping the tweet from displaying on the index page when it is submitted.  @wehdi

Comment: sorry my bad its has_many : tweets in  User model not in Tweet model check de modification above :s  
 Class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :tweets
end

Comment: its still coming up with the error of  'Couldn't find User without an ID'  and highlighting the first line of the create method. @wehdi

Comment: well, try the commande `rails g migration AddUserIdToMessages` and in this migration `def change
    add_column :tweets, :user_id, :integer
  end`

Comment: tweets already has a user_id which i did earlier. but still not working unfortuntly @wehdi

Comment: i try your code using my solution and it seem to work i will edit my post with my code

Comment: it is now working the same way that you did it, however it still breaks on the create method if i add a new tweet through a form @wehdi

Comment: There is no `user_id` in `param[:id]`. With devise you can do `@tweet = current_user.tweet.new(tweet_params)` in the create method. That will add the id of current authenticated user